# unable to view data of hive tables after update in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hivecontext, spark-hive

Case:
I have a table HiveTest which is a ORC table and transaction set true and loaded in spark shell and viewed data

```
var rdd= objHiveContext.sql("select * from HiveTest")
rdd.show()
```

--- **Able to view data**

Now I went to my hive shell or ambari updated the table , example

```
hive> update HiveTest set name='test'   ---Done and success
hive> select * from HiveTest -- able to view updated data
```

Now when I can come back to spark and run I cannot view any data except column names

```
scala>var rdd1= objHiveContext.sql("select * from HiveTest")
scala> rdd1.show()
```

**--This time only columns are printed , data is not coming**

Issue 2: Unable to update from spark sql when I run
scal>objHiveContext.sql("update HiveTest set name='test'") getting below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
Unsupported language features in query: INSERT INTO HiveTest values(1,'sudhir','Software',1,'IT')
TOK_QUERY 0, 0,17, 0
  TOK_FROM 0, -1,17, 0
    TOK_VIRTUAL_TABLE 0, -1,17, 0
      TOK_VIRTUAL_TABREF 0, -1,-1, 0
        TOK_ANONYMOUS 0, -1,-1, 0
      TOK_VALUES_TABLE 1, 6,17, 28
        TOK_VALUE_ROW 1, 7,17, 28
          1 1, 8,8, 28
          'sudhir' 1, 10,10, 30
          'Software' 1, 12,12, 39
          1 1, 14,14, 50
          'IT' 1, 16,16, 52
  TOK_INSERT 1, 0,-1, 12
    TOK_INSERT_INTO 1, 0,4, 12
      TOK_TAB 1, 4,4, 12
        TOK_TABNAME 1, 4,4, 12
          HiveTest 1, 4,4, 12
    TOK_SELECT 0, -1,-1, 0
      TOK_SELEXPR 0, -1,-1, 0
        TOK_ALLCOLREF 0, -1,-1, 0

scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for:
 TOK_VIRTUAL_TABLE 0, -1,17, 0
  TOK_VIRTUAL_TABREF 0, -1,-1, 0
    TOK_ANONYMOUS 0, -1,-1, 0
  TOK_VALUES_TABLE 1, 6,17, 28
    TOK_VALUE_ROW 1, 7,17, 28
      1 1, 8,8, 28
      'sudhir' 1, 10,10, 30
      'Software' 1, 12,12, 39
      1 1, 14,14, 50
      'IT' 1, 16,16, 52

org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.nodeToRelation(HiveQl.scala:1235)
```

This error is for Insert into statement same sort of error for update statement also.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried objHiveContext.refreshTable("HiveTest")?

Spark SQL aggressively caches Hive metastore data.

If an update happens outside of Spark SQL, you might experience some unexpected results as Spark SQL's version of the Hive metastore is out of date.

Here's some more info:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#metadata-refreshing

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

The docs mostly mention Parquet, but this likely applies to ORC and other file formats.

With JSON, for example, if you add new files into a directory outside of Spark SQL, you'll need to call hiveContext.refreshTable() within Spark SQL to see the new data.

Comment: ya that issue is resolved after refresh , can you look at second one mentioned

Answer (score 0):

sparksql does not have the update and delete transactions enabled uptil now. however insert still can be done.